# Is it possible to implicitly cast to a wrapper for UI?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a huge collection of objects of type **Person**, which I can not modify or inherit.
This is person.cs

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to have additional Information in my Grid (Wpf Datagrid) which I have to lookup in a IValueConverter. But IValueConverters are a bad solution if you have a lot of Persons ( > 500 )

My idea was to create a wrapper like this:

```
public class PersonWrapper
{
    public Person Content { get; set; }

    public string GetAdditionalInfo
    {
        get { return Helper.GetMagicInfo(Content); }
    }
}
```

With this trick I can avoid having a IValueConverter.

*Now comes my question:*

Can I implicitly (with MarkupExtension or with TypeConverter) "wrap" my class for use in Binding?

---

*Edit:*
I wrote a TypeConverter and used a TemplateSelector.
The TypeConverter:

```
public class PersonTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(Person);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var s = value as PersonWrapper;
        if (s == null)
            return new Person();
        return s.Content;
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return new PersonWrapper() {Content = value as Person};
    }
}
```

And added the Attribute to Person.cs

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(PersonTypeConverter))]
```

And I used it like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="dt" DataType="{x:Type local:PersonWrapper}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="{Binding FirstName}" />
            <Label Content="{Binding LastName}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:CTemplateSelector DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource dt}" x:Key="CTemplateSelector" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding OurText}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CTemplateSelector}" />
</Grid>
```

The TemplateSelector:

```
public class CTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    /// <summary>When overridden in a derived class, returns a <see cref="T:System.Windows.DataTemplate" /> based on custom logic.</summary>
    /// <returns>Returns a <see cref="T:System.Windows.DataTemplate" /> or null. The default value is null.</returns>
    /// <param name="item">The data object for which to select the template.</param>
    /// <param name="container">The data-bound object.</param>
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(item?.GetType());
        return DefaultTemplate;
    }

    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate
    {
        get ;
        set ; 
    }
}
```

But the TemplateSelector always prints out Person as type.

Comment: add implicit operator between two types in the wrapper to change between the two types

Comment: good idea Nkosi, but even with this solution, the Person is not implicitly converted in a wrapper.

Comment: How are you getting the collection? using the implicit operator idea have the collection be of the wrapper type and populate it will the person as they are retrieved from persistence store. So the data source of the grid will be of type wrapper and is passed the person classes

Comment: I can not. Because the collection is hierarchical (my example here is very stripped down) and comes from NHibernate, so I had the idea with this implicit wrapper.

Comment: I understand. Was just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get away with subclassing from your person object such as

```
public class MyPerson : Person
{
    public string FirstLast
    { get { return string.Format( "{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName ); }}

    public string LastFirst
    { get { return string.Format( "{0}, {1}", LastName, FirstName ); }}

    public string YourOtherContext
    { get { return WhateverFunctionToGetContext( this ); }}
}
```

Then you have your other function that return the string you want to present.  Your bindings get all the default properties of the person structure and you have just extended with these new properties without any converters.  When the grid is bound to them, it calls the getters just like any other and returns that value.